# CSS Modules Import is not applying css to html for "react-scripts": "2.0.4"

Tags: css, reactjs, css-modules

I am working on a react.js project and trying to use css modules. We have react-scripts 2.0.4 which should include css modules. However when importing the css file it returns an empty object.

I have a css file 
App.modules.css

```
.gridLayout {
    display: 'grid';
    grid-template-areas: 'sideBar sideBar mainBody mainBody mainBody';
}

.sideBar {
    grid-area: 'sideBar';
}

.mainBody {
    grid-area: 'mainBody';
}
```

In my App.js

```
import styles from './App.modules.css';
console.log(styles);
....
```

The output is {}

and there appears to be no css applied when I inspect the page.

Also

When I try running `npm run build`

It gives this error with the css

```
> deedee@0.1.0 build /Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:61
        fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^

Error: Chunk.entrypoints: Use Chunks.addGroup instead
    at Chunk.set (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/webpack/lib/Chunk.js:829:9)
    at /Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:176:40
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Compilation.<anonymous> (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:171:18)
    at Compilation.applyPluginsAsyncSeries (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/react-scripts-cssmodules/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:206:13)
    at Compilation.seal (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/react-scripts-cssmodules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:605:8)
    at applyPluginsParallel.err (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/react-scripts-cssmodules/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:508:17)
    at /Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/react-scripts-cssmodules/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:289:11
    at /Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/react-scripts-cssmodules/node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/index.js:60:9
    at tryCatcher (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:694:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (/Users/sdrafahl/code/DeeDee/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:131:9)
```

Would anyone know why css modules are not working?

Comment: When you run your app, are the CSS styles getting applied as expected to your elements? The reason to import CSS into your JS isn't to make it available to code in any way. It's simply to bundle the CSS with your outputted files. The result of a CSS import being `{}` is the expected behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that. When I run the project and connect via localhost the css properties are not applied and after inspecting they dont appear to have the css applied.

Comment: @jered I think you might be thinking of importing styles with create-react-app 1, with the latest release, it includes CSS modules which actually makes your styles available in your JS file. https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules

Answer (score 0):

Look at your import, there is a typo in the filename. Try changing it to

`import styles from './App.Module.css';`

If that doesn't work, it might be an issue with it being in Title Case. Try changing the file name and import to `App.module.css` (per these docs: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet)

Comment: Thanks for your response but that was a typo of me typing it on Stack Overflow. I will correct it. I also tried changing the cases and that didnt work.